# Spring Data JPA Required request body is missing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using the following class as an entity, and a controller class to write data on it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class TableA {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, name="Id")
    private BigInteger id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, name="Name")
    private String name;
  
    //Setters Getters
}

@RestController
public class TableAController {
    @Autowired
    TableARepository tableARepository;
    
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @PostMapping(value="/CreateTableA") 
    public void createTableA(@RequestBody TableA newTableA){
        TableA tableA = new TableA();
        tableA = newTableA;
        tableARepository.save(tableA);
    }
}
```

The `Id` column value will be generated by the DB, so I used the `@JsonProperty`. But, when I test the REST API using the following as a request:

```
{
    "name" : "Leo Messi"
}
```

I am getting the aforementioned error message. I have also tried the `@JsonIgnore` property with the same result. Is there a way to except the id property from the deserialization process? Or should I use another class dedicated the API Request? I am not comfortable with creating different models for every new API.

I am not sure if I should focus on resolving the error, or if I should design the classes using a Design Pattern that never produces it.

Comment: Add your pom.xml, build.gradle, or build.sbt, as an edit to your question

Comment: Add the error message too.

Comment: It's a basic Spring boot app with spring-boot-starter-web, postgresql and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa as dependencies. I would prefer to keep the question short as it's more readable.

Comment: BTW Do not use the entity in your API. It makes only problems

Comment: The error is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing com.spring.TableAController.createTableA(com.spring.TableA)

Comment: Workaround proposal: use a (tableA) dto (not containing "id"). `@RequestParameter String name` seems also sufficient for this case (instead of RequestBody).

Comment: @xerx593 both valid points but that would mean a DTO for every DAO and i'm not sure that's a good option in terms of code complexity. The RequestParameter would also work but i would prefer to keep arguments on an object level.

Comment: *but that would mean a DTO for every DAO and i'm not sure that's a good option in terms of code complexity.* that is best practrice. It can also be that your dto are not equals to the entities and the second point is, that an etity is more than you see!